# I'm trying to add jquery 1.9 to bootstrap but in project use jquery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I have a project, old one wich uses jQ 1.7.2 but in console I'm getting an error from Bootstrap telling BS needs jQuery 1.9 or higher. I can't add jQ 1.9 to whole project cause nothing will work. Tryin to use jQuery.noConflict() between js requiers in application.coffee but no matter how I order it I get this:

> TypeError: jQuery is not a function

jQ 1.7.2 getting from gem, jQ 1.9 and BS are files in assets
code in application.coffee:

```
#= require vendor/browser-update
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require jquery.ui.core
#= require jquery.ui.widget
#= require jquery.ui.mouse
#= require jquery.ui.position
#= require jquery.ui.draggable
#= require jquery.ui.droppable
#= require jquery.ui.button
#= require jquery.ui.dialog
#= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
#= require jquery.ui.tabs
#= require jquery.ui.progressbar
#= require jquery.ui.sortable
#= require jquery-form

#= require_tree ./vendor
#= require js-routes
#= require twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip
#= require twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover
#= require variables
#= require_tree ./libraries
#= require profile
#= require rails-timeago
#= require locales/jquery.timeago.pl.js
#= require_tree ./application

# Relics Angular App
#= require lodash
#= require angular
#= require angular-sanitize
#= require angular-cookies
#= require angular-prevent-default
#= require oz-container-helper

#= require angular-google-maps
#= require angular-dragdrop
#= require angular-ui-sortable
#= require angular-bootstrap
#= require ./angular/init
#= require ./angular/router
#= require_tree ./angular

# priv js
#= require oz-edit-modal-request
#= require oz-contrast-changer

# bootstrap js
#= require jquery-1.9.1
#= require bootstrap.js
#= require bootstrap-sprockets
$jq191 = $.noConflict(true)
```

I also tried adding jQ 1.9 before BS and jQ 1.7.2 but still it doesn't work.

Comment: It's really best to use a single version of jQuery, so upgrading the entire project to 1.9 (or better yet, 1.12 if you must stay on the 1.x branch) will save a lot of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I think that might help is to use an older version of bootstrap. Otherwise, update all the code to 1.9 and up standards.

Comment: Updating is the best solution, I now. If I could do that I would :)